# CodeIgniter session lost after redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a project that use CI 3 I developed on localhost in Windows using XAMPP, and final product was deployed on Debian Apache server. I tried to logged in but it's redirected back to default controller. 
I tried to enter the wrong login and it's show the error correctly, but when I entered the right login it keeps comeback to my login controller. 
Here is my login controller (Auth.php) :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Auth extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_m');
    if ($this->session->userdata('akses') == 'admin') {
        redirect('dashboard');
    }
    elseif ($this->session->userdata('akses')=='user') {
        redirect('user');
    }
}
public function index() {
    $this->load->view('login_v');

}

public function login() {
    $nip=$this->input->post('nip');
    $password=$this->input->post('password');

    $query = $this->user_m->login($nip);
    if ($query->num_rows()==1)
    {
        $row = $query->row();
        if ($password == $this->bcrypt->check_password($password,$row->password)) {    
            $data_login= array(
            'nip'=>$row->nip,
            'id_pegawai'=>$row->id_pegawai,
            'akses'=>$row->akses
            );
            echo $this->session->set_userdata($data_login);
            $akses = $this->session->userdata('akses');
            if ($akses=='admin') {
                redirect('dashboard');
            }
            elseif ($akses=='user') {
                redirect('user');
            }       
        }
        else {
            echo "<script>alert('Gagal login: Cek nip, password!');history.go(-1);</script>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('Gagal login: Cek nip, password!');history.go(-1);</script>";
         }
    }
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me?
**UPDATE**
When I checked the session after redirect, it always pass a null value with new id session. Even I tried the [native session](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session) class still didn't help it.

Comment: It sounds like your user or dashboard controllers might be kicking you back to the login page if you are checking for valid credentials in those. Have you tried to comment out the redirects and check that the Auth is setting your session variables correctly. And check the same thing in your Dashboard and Users Controller... That's all I can suggest at the moment.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw ok I'll try it

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I've tried to trace the session, and what happened is when redirectng the session is automatically cleared, in result when I check authority access it returned false and redirected back to login page

Comment: Are you autoloading the sessions library?

Comment: yes I autoload it, normally it should be not problem right?

Comment: No that's fine, else you would have been getting errors anyway...

Comment: Is your apache server running on a hosted site or on a local development site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125303/discussion-between-timbrownlaw-and-ibnu-agiels-althur).